# Extremely Simple reliable way to switch logic level signals

Tags: relay, pwm, components, safety

I am designing a failsafe system for an Unmanned Aerial Vehicle, and it needs to be able to switch 6 PWM outputs from one source to another. My initial thought was to use a series of logic level relays but they cannot fulfill all the requirements that I have listed below, what are some alternative methods I can use?

- Survive intense vibration (~.3G at 300-600Hz)
- Fail safe, in the event of a total loss of power the signals will flow without impediment
- Listed MTBF or MCBF (hoping for around 1,000,000 Hours or 100,000 Cycles per channel)

Comment: Not even latching relays?

Comment: The problem is that if it is latched in the wrong position they won't revert to the Failsafe position after the loss of power

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean by "in the event".

Comment: What's generating the PWM when there is no power? Can your switches be powered by the same source for the PWM?

Comment: I don't consider 0.3G to be **intense** vibration.  Pretty much any relay on the market today will have absolutely no problem with that level of vibration.

Comment: What total series resistance will your signals tolerate?  Can you not use Photo-MOS relays?  These are available with NO and NC contacts and most (if not all) will survive vibration levels of several hundreds of Gs vibration.

Comment: The board is independently powered, and the power "Should" be more hardened than the main power source but in the event of the failsafe power supply failing and the Main is still up I want to be sure that it switches to the correct position.

Comment: @DwayneReid I am unsure of the actual vibration levels, but it is going on a Gas powered RC helicopter, I think that it might be higher than that, I haven't been able to find Relays rated for continuous vibration, perhaps I haven't been looking in the right places

Comment: @DwayneReid Photo-MOS relays look like they would work but they are all only only xPST not SPDT, total resistance should not be more than around 60-80 Ohms less is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IXYS LCC120](http://www.clare.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/1D7C2FC89A5985B985256A2C006889F1/$file/Lcc120.pdf) is a solid-state OptoMOS relay with a Form C (SPDT) contact.  It can switch up to 170 mA with a maximum on resistance of 20 Ω (16 Ω typical).

The datasheet has no spec on vibration but I can't believe that would be a problem with solid state relays.  Available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LCC120STR/CLA254CT-ND/1212865).